# Invitation.getVariant is always -1?

Tags: android, google-play-games

No matter what I place in the `TurnBasedMatchConfig` of the `createMatch` the Invitation always gives me a `-1`. But when the invitation is accepted the resulting `TurnBasedMatch` gives me the correct variant.

```
TurnBasedMatchConfig tbmc = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder()
                            .addInvitedPlayers(invitees)
                            .setVariant(2)
                            .setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria)
                            .build();

Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch(getApiClient(), tbmc)
```

`match.getVariant()` gives 2

`invitation.getVariant()` gives -1

What am I doing wrong?